# JUnit Test Compiling

Tags: java, junit

I would like to compile JUnit from windows command line.

I have a project that contains many different packages. I can compile and run this project from the command line. However, I have difficulties to compile JUnit class that I have created.

My JUnit class imports only my model and uses the methods to ensure that my model is correct. Therefore, there is a dependency.
My question is that how can I compile and run my JUnit class without using ant?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

If you already manage to compile the rest of your project, then adding JUnit to `javac`'s command line should allow you to compile JUnit-dependent code.

Try adding `-cp /full/path/to/your/junit.jar` to the command line.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to include the JUnit jar in your class path.

```
java -cp junit-4.8.1.jar;yourfiles.jar com.your.class
```